# Question for the code required to make the def update func in python to actually update something

Tags: python

I'm supposed to make a code for a class called employee, in the class I have: `def __init__ (self, iD="", N="", etc..)` later on I have to use a method I believe that is called def update and I'm supposed to write a code for that to work to update any information changed on the first one but I have no idea how to write the code in order for the def update to actually work, so could someone please tell me how to do it or guide me through?

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, iD="", sN="", sL="", sA="", sCity=""):
        # missing code

    def update(self, iD="", sN="", sL="", sA="", sCity=""):
        # what do i code in order for this to work???
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Usually in such methods code looks like: `self.iD=iD`, `self.sN=sN`, etc

Comment: Likely the code in the `update` would be the same as in the `__init__()`.

Comment: I suppose you have an method to update the parameters. As mentioned in an earlier comments the method `__init__()` will have `self.id = id`, etc and method `update()` `self.id = id`, etc. Then you make an instance of Employee like: john = `Employee(id=1)` and you can update with `john.update(id=2)`  ... be careful though if you update like this all your initial settings if not defined in the update parameters will be set to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

The most likable is that your `__init__()` method contained this:

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, iD="", sN="", sL="", sA="", sCity=""):
        self.iD = iD
        self.sN = sN
        self.sL = sL
        self.sA = sA
        self.sCity = sCity
```

And surely your `update()` method should go like this:

```
    def update(self, iD="", sN="", sL="", sA="", sCity=""):
        self.iD = iD
        self.sN = sN
        self.sL = sL
        self.sA = sA
        self.sCity = sCity
```

Comment: In which case, `__init__` should simply use `update` instead of repeating the assignments.

Comment: And arguably, `__init__` should *require* the values, instead of using meaningless defaults (despite the signature in the original question).

Comment: @chepner, I agree with you. I understand that it is some sort of legacy code, or something like that

Comment: @Bruno raised a good point in the comments. Just because no value is passed to `update` for a particular field doesn't mean that field should be overwritten with `""`.